# Calculate the number theory function $\sum_{n \equiv a(\bmod q)} \frac{\phi(n)-\mu(n)}{n^{s+1}}$

Tags: analytic-number-theory

I am trying to simplify the function:
$$\sum_{n \equiv a(\bmod q)} \frac{\phi(n)-\mu(n)}{n^{s+1}}=\frac{1}{\phi\left(q^{\prime}\right)} \sum_\chi \bar{\chi}\left(a^{\prime}\right) \sum_{n^{\prime}=1}^{\infty} \chi\left(n^{\prime}\right) \frac{\phi\left(b n^{\prime}\right)-\mu\left(b n^{\prime}\right)}{\left(b n^{\prime}\right)^{s+1}}$$

where $b=(a,q), n'=n/b, a'=a/b, q'=q/b$.
to the function:
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \sum_{n \equiv a(\bmod q)} \frac{\phi(n)-\mu(n)}{n^{s+1}} \\
& \quad=\frac{1}{b^{s+1} \phi\left(q^{\prime}\right)} \sum_\chi \frac{\bar{\chi}\left(a^{\prime}\right)(\phi(b) L(s, \chi)-\mu(b))}{L(s+1, \chi) \prod_{p \mid b}\left(1-\chi(p) p^{-s-1}\right)}
\end{aligned}
$$

But there is some problem due to the product of $b$ and $n'$ since they are not coprime necessartily. what's more, I am confused why the $\prod_{p|b}(1-\chi(p)p_{-s-1})$ comes out because I know how to prove the identity:
$$
\sum_n \frac{\chi(n)(\phi(n)-\mu(n))}{n^{s+1}}=\frac{L(s, \chi)-1}{L(s+1, \chi)}
$$
Do you know how to deal with it? Thank you for advance !

Comment: Just use the fact that
$$\phi(bn') = \frac{\phi(b) \phi(n') (b,n')}{\phi((b,n'))}, \qquad \mu(bn') = \mu(b) \mu(n') 1_{(b,n')=1}.$$

Comment: But it is still difference between the final equation. I get the thing:$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{b^{s+1}} \frac{(\phi(b) L(s, \chi))}{L(s+1, \chi) \prod_{p \mid b,p \mid n'}\left(1-p^{-1}\right)}
\end{aligned}
$$
and
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{b^{s+1}} \frac{\mu(b)*1_{(b,n')}}{L(s+1, \chi)}
\end{aligned}, not the $$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{b^{s+1}} \frac{(\phi(b) L(s, \chi)-\mu(b))}{L(s+1, \chi) \prod_{p \mid b}\left(1-\chi(p) p^{-s-1}\right)}
\end{aligned}
$$. @PeterHumphries

Comment: oh, i didn't see you posted it here too.  on the stackexchange one i posted an answer for you